# Issue with wordpress and thumbnail size

Tags: wordpress

I made one shop site in wordpress and everything was just fine until few days ago. When I try to assign featured image to post image is not cropped right. I added like 50 products and everything was just fine but starting from few days ago its broken. None of the code is altered but now when I assign featured image I get [this result.](http://hampshireantiqueclocks.co.uk/wall-clocks/) You can notice difference between nicely cropped images from past and two new products . What can cause this problem? In template page I have some code :

```
 <?php /* The loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="blogContent">
    <h1 class="blogHeading"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('featuredImageCropped', array('class' => 'slikalevo')); ?></a>
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'featuredImageCropped', 310, 150, true );
```

Tthat code worked fine but now its broken why?.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well what i saw from the url is that the size for the image you have given 310 but your image holder div named class'blogContent' is having maximum size 250 after the padding of 30 from width 280. So you should make the image to 250x150.

Comment: yeah thats ok i noticed that but real problem is (refresh page again), its croped in the middle. Look other thumbnails on page or whole site they are looking good like zoomed out images not croped in middle :/

Comment: @MitrovicSrdjan Are you able to solve this? If yes then do share.

Answer (score 0):

The width of your images is 310px, while you have set .blogContent to a width of 250px and gave it 15px padding. That doesn't fit.

Change your add_image_size into: 
add_image_size( 'featuredImageCropped', 250, 121, true );

Then change your css. Remove the padding from .blogContent and add it to h1.blogHeading and to .blogContent p.

Answer (score 0):

Whole problem was to set croped to false

```
add_image_size( 'featuredImageCropped', 250, 150, false );
```

i just dont know how it worked before